# Ignore deprecated warning in Angular 2 Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, material-design, karma-runner, angular

I'm currently using Angular 2 (or angular 4) to run some tests in jasmine/karma. The problem is that I'm also using Material design that doesn't fully support angular 4 yet, this makes it impossible to test components as it will always throw the following error:

```
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead

("[WARNING ->]<template><div class="mat-autocomplete-panel" 
role="listbox" [id]="id" [ngClass]="_getClassList()" #p")
```

I can't stop using 'template' as I'm not using it in my view, it's being used on a lower level by Material Design.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to ignore or suppress the warning? (seeing as the code runs fine when building the app)**

edit: Md2 seems to have solved this issue: https://github.com/Promact/md2/issues/125 (I can't vouch for this)

Comment: The @angular package like @angular/material requires angular 2, so it's not compatible with angular 4. By the semantic versioning rules of npm, ^2.3.0 allows only version greater than or equal to 2.3.0 but still with the major version 2, so only 2.x.y where x >= 3.

You'll have to wait until they release a version for Angular 4. When the pull request #3752 is merged,  Otherwise you need to wait until they publish it to npm

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Still hoping there's some sort of annotation that suppresses it all. It's weird that it works and throws no errors til you're testing it.

Comment: For you getting any warning message.

Comment: When running my app I do not, only when testing. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: While running the app in browser?Are you getting any template deprecated error

Comment: Just realized it doesn't throw an error, but it does indeed throw a warning (the same as in the post)